# Is there a way to call prefersStatusBarHidden without View controller-based status bar appearance set to NO?

Tags: ios, swift

There are lots of questions about toggling status bar visibility in iOS. I know them all but not this one (see my question above).

These are my cases:

1. **View controller-based status bar appearance** in my info.plist is **NO** - this is necessary because I'm toggling my view controllers' status bar color almost every screen. I don't want to start bothering with my base controllers again with this.
2. The key **Status bar is initially hidden** is set to **YES**. - Well for now, I really need to hide my status bar in my splash screen until the third party I use updates to let developers configure it not to mess with the status bar.
3. With the **#2 case** above, the first screen has now no status bar.
4. `Status bar is initially hidden` works even if I have the **#1 case** above, but is deprecated.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can add `statusbarappearence` method in particular view controller.

Comment: Is your *splash* screen really a *launch* screen? If not, just leave the status bar on the launch screen - it really shouldn't be up for more than 2 seconds - and get to your splash screen and beyond, manipulating both hidden and appearance in code by overriding two method - **prefersStatusBarHidden** and **preferredStatusBarStyle**. Set this in every VC and you've guaranteed the behavior you want.

Comment: I'm toggling the status bar style of EACH view controllers by each classes by calling a common function as extension of UIViewController. The function uses UIApplication, like so: 
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent .... and yes, it's a launchscreen. A storyboard. You're right, it may not be really important to fix.